# Custom error message under picklist

Tags: picklist, validation-rule

Currently the validation error is a predefined message for the custom picklist `Banner__c`.

[image].

I wrote the following validation error to create custom error message.

[image]

It seems to be an esay task, but nothing is woking in my case. Still the predefined error message is coming. I tries the following rule for this.

> ISPICKVAL(Banner__c, "")
>
> ISPICKVAL(Banner__c, "NULL")
>
> ISBLANK(TEXT(Banner__c))
>
> TEXT(Banner__c) = ""

Answer (score 3):

Uncheck the box on the Picklist field edit screen that requires a value.

Edit: Also uncheck the box on the page layout editor that makes the field required.

Comment: Its already unchecked.

Comment: Uncheck the box on the Page Layout edit screen that makes the field required.